# Why nested dictionary is filled wrongly?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have an empty nested dictionary of such a design:

```
{'PEAR': {'GREEN': [], 'YELLOW': [], 'RED': []}, 'APPLE': {'GREEN': [], 'YELLOW': [], 'RED': []}, 'COURGETTE': {'GREEN': [], 'YELLOW': [], 'RED': []}}
```

And here is my code:

```
dictSub = {'RED' : [], 'GREEN' : [], 'YELLOW' : []}
arrMainCodes = ['APPLE', 'PEAR', 'COURGETTE']
dictAll = {}
numbers = {1 : [1, 2, 3], 2 : [4, 56, 7], 3 : [8, 2, 10]}

for item in arrMainCodes:
    dictAll[item] = dictSub
print(dictAll)
dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(478)
dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(47)
dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(8)
print(dictAll)
ITEM = [478, 7, 56]
for i in ITEM:
    if i not in dictAll['PEAR']['RED']:
        dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(i)
print(dictAll)
```

I am trying to fill it in such a manner, that only sublist `'RED'` of key `'PEAR'` will be filled. However, my result looks like that:

```
{'PEAR': {'GREEN': [], 'YELLOW': [], 'RED': [478, 47, 8, 7, 56]}, 'APPLE': {'GREEN': [], 'YELLOW': [], 'RED': [478, 47, 8, 7, 56]}, 'COURGETTE': {'GREEN': [], 'YELLOW': [], 'RED': [478, 47, 8, 7, 56]}}
```

As you can see everything `'RED'` is filled, while I want only red pear to be filled.

What am I doing wrong? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all references to a single dictionary. Your first four statements are the only ones that actually create new dictionary objects; your `for` loop just creates additional names that all refer to the same one.

You can solve that by replacing this assignment:

```
dictAll[item] = dictSub
```

with this:

```
dictAll[item] = dictSub.copy()
```

That will get you separate dictionaries, but each one will still have references to the same lists. To make sure everything is a fresh copy, use `deepcopy()` instead:

```
dictAll[item] = dictSub.deepcopy()
```

Comment: I used dictSub.copy(), But It still gave me the same result.Because the lists inside are referenced to same thing every time I guess.

Comment: In that case use `deepcopy` instead of just `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is python. Python never copies any objects. SO whenever you assign an dict or array keeps a reference and whenever you change one, changes will reflect in all references.
You can do this.

```
arrMainCodes = ['APPLE', 'PEAR', 'COURGETTE']
dictAll = {}
numbers = {1 : [1, 2, 3], 2 : [4, 56, 7], 3 : [8, 2, 10]}

for item in arrMainCodes:
    dictAll[item]={'RED' : [], 'GREEN' : [], 'YELLOW' : []}
print(dictAll)
dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(478)
dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(47)
dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(8)
print(dictAll)
ITEM = [478, 7, 56]
for i in ITEM:
    if i not in dictAll['PEAR']['RED']:
        dictAll['PEAR']['RED'].append(i)
print(dictAll)
```

This will create separate dict with new lists every time.